# Excel - Copy-paste (transpose) between workbooks using VB

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy the values of a range of cells and then pasting it on a different  workbook using VBA. However, the code only paste the first copied cell, leaving the rest of the range in blank. I couldn't identify my mistake.

This is the code:

```
Sub Data()
Dim wbk As Workbook`
Dim wks As Worksheet`
carp = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Bases de datos\"
a = "Cuadros_de_salida_IMAE.xls"
Application.EnableEvents = False
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(carp & a)
Set wks = wbk.Worksheets("Activ")
Application.EnableEvents = True
wks.Rows.Hidden = False


b = "D"
c0 = 9
c1 = 25
E = "IMAE"
f0 = "G"
f1 = "W"
g = 6
iniRow = c0
finRow = c1
wks.Range(b & iniRow & ":" & b & finRow).End(xlToRight).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(E).Range(f0 & g).PasteSpecial  Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, Transpose:=True

Windows(a).Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Thanks. I really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to back-piece the code you have... seems like lots of unnecessary variables/references.

```
Dim LR as Long
LR = Cells(wks.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 

Dim LC as Long
LC = Cells(wks.Columns.Count, 1).End(xlToLeft).Column

wks.RANGE(Cells(9,7),Cells(LR,LC)).Copy

Worksheets(E).Range(Cells(6,7),Cells(LR-3,LC)).PasteSpecial  Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, Transpose:=True   'LR-3 because G9 and G6 row difference
```

That should be a decent start for you.

Comment: I can usually just select the starting cell (G6) for the paste location and excel/vba will define the range.  I coded in from G6 to the end of range (dynamic).

Comment: Thanks Cyril, your suggestion was really helpful.

Comment: Did this answer your question, @AlvaroLopezE. ?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way to do this but the issue is with the `wks.Range(b & iniRow & ":" & b & finRow).End(xlToRight).Copy` statement. If you change this to:

```
wks.Range(b & iniRow & ":" & b & finRow).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight).Copy
```

Your code should work. When in doubt use the macro recorder :)

Comment: He's using wks.Range("G6:G25").End(xlToRight).Copy as his line (following back his variables).  Would you not want to avoid selections and speed up that process?  You know the final row, but the final column is the only mission parameter, hence the xlToRight.

Comment: Thanks for your response.